# Why cannot a function be continuous at multiple limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

I read this statement in "The Way of Analysis" -

*A function $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ in its domain that is a limit-point iff $d$ has a limit at $x_0$ and the value of $f(x_0)$ equals $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$.

My question is - if the domain of the function has multiple limit points, does it mean that the function will not be continuous at the other limit points? Why not?

**EDIT:** I read that the limit of a function, if it exists, is unique. I understand that this means that the function can continuous at most one limit point. Is that not the case?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The behavior at one limit point has little, if anything, to do with the behavior at any other limit point. A domain typically has infinitely many limit points....

Comment: @T.Bongers Sorry - my bad. I forgot to mention an important part (an obvious side-effect of multitasking!) - I read that the limit of a function, if it exists, is unique. I understand that this means that the function can continuous at most one limit point. Is that not the case? (I will also edit the question to reflect this).

Comment: The limit of a function **at a point** is unique, so there can be at most one number $L$ satisfying $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ for any $a$. But $L$ can change if you change $a$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh God! I feel stupid now. Thank you so much for this! I missed that "at a point" part.

Comment: No problem; it can be confusing when there are several levels of quantifiers going on.